# Create a search using Collections.binarySearch

Tags: java, servlets, java-web-start

I'm doing a web application and I need to implement a site search. The parameters that will be searched in the search-field, are Integer. I use this class to compare two list items

```
public class Comparators {

public static class CompareByNumber implements Comparator<Flight>, Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -2382790006724690579L;

        @Override
        public int compare(Flight f1, Flight f2) {
            return f1.getNumber().compareTo(f2.getNumber());
        }

    }
}
```

After that I do the following, I'm trying to use binarySearch. But I do not know what to transmit as a key. To search for what the user enters into the search-field. I will be grateful for your help!!!

```
List<Flight> flight = db.findFlightsByAircompany(aircompany);
String search = request.getParameter("search");
        if ("number".equals(search)){
            Collections.sort(flight, new Comparators.CompareByNumber());
            Collections.binarySearch(flight, "", new Comparators.CompareByNumber());
        }
```

Comment: *FYI:* Binary search is only good if you need to do multiple searches of an already sorted list. Doing sort + binary search together like that is not effective. A simple sequential search would be faster.

Comment: Okay, can you give me a simple example?)

Comment: why have you Serialized the class ??

Comment: Instead of doing all this, you can simply put the values in a Map<Integer> and search. You will not need to the comparator as well.

Comment: I use the serialization, because the data is taken and saved in the database

Comment: @VIRICH You need an *example* of a sequential search? Really? `for (Flight f : flight) { if (f.getNumber().equals(number)) { /* found */; break; } }`

Comment: @Andreas Oh, I thought you meant something else)I already tried this and decided that it would be easier for me to use binary.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a Flight object whose `getNumber()` method returns the integer you are looking for.